# Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method

Tags: ember.js

Pretty new to Ember so maybe someone can help me out. I keep running across this error and have no idea how to solve it.

```
Ember             : 2.5.1
Ember Data        : 2.5.3
```

Below is my `router.js`.

```
//app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('organization', {path: '/organization/:id'}, function(){
    this.route('about', { path: '/about' });
    this.route('admin', { path: '/admin' }, function(){
        this.route('team', { path: '/team/:team_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

The `organization/:id/about` and `organization/:id/admin` routes work fine. But when I try to load the `organization/:id/admin/team/:team_id` route, the error is thrown. Below is the `routes/organization/admin/team.js` file:

```
//app/routes/organization/admin/team.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model(params) {
        let organization = this.modelFor('organization');
        return organization.get('team');
    }

});
```

Not really sure what other information I should post, so please ask for any additional information you may think is necessary to help debug. My guess is it's something pretty simple and I'm completely oblivious to it.

**EDIT**

I've added a couple more files to help diagnose the problem:

```
//app/routes/organization.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('organization', params.organization_id)
  }
});

//app/routes/organization/admin.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    changeValue(){
      this.currentModel.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Where `currentModel` is the model for the `organization` route. I've removed the `organization.admin.team` model hook for now and am just testing a

`{{#link-to 'organization.admin.team' model.team.id}} Team {{/link-to}}`

in a component rendered in the `organization.admin` template where I pass `model=model`. But now I get the same error (Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method) in the Javascript console when rendering the `organization.admin` template.

Comment: try this.modelFor('admin') ...provide organization and admin model structure..

Comment: @kumkanillam tried `this.modelFor('admin')` but that was `undefined`. Tried `this.modelFor('organization.admin')` which returns a Class with the organization id. Then tried calling `team` on that, which was a ComputedProperty. But no XHR request was sent off and a team was never loaded via the Ember Inspector :(

Comment: Could you make a twiddle? https://ember-twiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

If you pass Object to `{{#link-to}}` helper. It skips the model hook. So you could basically send `{{#link-to 'team' organization.team}}`Without having to write "model" hook.

"It makes sense and it might save a request to the server but it is, admittedly, not intuitive. An ingenious way around that is to pass in, not the object itself, but its id" - https://www.toptal.com/emberjs/the-8-most-common-ember-js-developer-mistakes".

So you should do

*hbs*

```
{{#link-to 'team' organization.team.id}} Link to team management {{/link-to}}
```

*route*

```
model(params) {
   return this.store.findRecord('team', params.team_id) 
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and updated my original question based on the results I got. Basically the error is thrown on rendering the {{#link-to}} when accessing `team` on `organization`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use modelFor('parent') method to get organization model.
 like that

//app/routes/organization/admin/team.js
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model(params) {
        let organization = this.modelFor('parent');
        return this.store.findRecord('team', params.team_id)
    }

});
```

i think you wants to do something like that.
basically ember does not support nested routes.

Comment: you can use this gem to perform nested routes operations
https://github.com/amiel/ember-data-url-templates

Comment: `this.modelFor('parent')` was undefined when I tried to log it. And `return this.store.findRecord('team', params.team_id)` threw the same error. I'll definitely look more deeply into that addon. That had come up a bit in my searching yesterday but hadn't really understood it. Thanks!

Comment: @jsquirrelz did you ever find an answer? I'm running into a similar issue.